# Como alinhar checkbox e label com bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

O resultado desse meu form coloca os checkbox e labels em linha, o que está correto, mas não consigo achar uma classe do bootstrap que faça o label alinhas com o checkbox.

Como eu faço isso?

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="/video/genresfilter" method="post" class="form-inline">

<label><input id="Check1" name="Check1" type="checkbox" value="Check1">Check1</input></label>

<label><input id="Check2" name="Check2" type="checkbox" value="Check2">Check2</input></label>
                                                                                            
<label><input id="Check3" name="Check3" type="checkbox" value="Check3">Check3</input></label>
                                                                                              
</form>
```

**ATUALIZANDO**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A foto acima é o resultado atual, quero que a caixa do checkbox fique alinhada com a label Checkbox1, no resultado atual parece que a caixa está alinhada acima e precisaria ficar centralizada.

O centro da caixa deve coincidir com o centro da letra "C" da palavra Checkbox...

Comment: Alinhar verticalmente?

Comment: Horizontal, manda executar o código que vai aparecer eles na horizonta sem alinhar.

Comment: Desculpe pela lerdeza, mas ainda não o compreendi. Você pode fazer uma imagem simulando o que você deseja?

Comment: Coloquei a imagem do resultado atual, o resultado esperado eu não consigo fazer (por isso perguntei rsrs). Mas expliquei mais detalhado o que eu quero. Ve se da para entender agora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se isso lhe serve:

```css
label {
    display: inline-block;
}
input {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="/video/genresfilter" method="post" class="form-inline">

<label><input id="Check1" name="Check1" type="checkbox" value="Check1">Check1</label>

<label><input id="Check2" name="Check2" type="checkbox" value="Check2">Check2</label>
                                                                                            
<label><input id="Check3" name="Check3" type="checkbox" value="Check3">Check3</label>
                                                                                              
</form>
```

Retirei os "fechamentos" das `input`.

Comment: Ficou legal, mas muda o top para 2px, fica melhor com 2 de top, obrigado!